# Export in Makefile, access in Shell

Tags: bash, makefile

This is the content of makefile:

```
all:
     export name="foo"
    ./s.sh
```

This is the content of s.sh:

```
echo "Name is:"
echo $name
```

Running **make all** will have this output:

```
export name="foo"
./s.sh
Name is:
```

How can I access the exported variable in my shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line of each recipe runs in its own shell.   Thus, when each line finishes, that line's shell terminates, and it forgets all the variables that were set in it before it begins executing the next recipe line.   You can catenate the lines to make them run in one shell as so:

```
all:
     export name="foo"; \
    ./s.sh
```

Comment: Alternatively if it's really just a single command you can use `name="foo" ./s.sh` to set variables for that command's invocation only.